# exclude part of the select not to consider date where clause

Tags: oracle

i have a select(water readings, previous water reading, other columns) , a "where clause" that is based on date water reading date. however for previous water reading it must not consider the where clause.  I want to get previous meter reading regardless where clause date range.

looked at union problem is that i have to use the same clause,

```
 SELECT
 WATERREADINGS.name,
 WATERREADINGS.date,    
 LAG( WATERREADINGS.meter_reading,1,NULL) OVER(
 PARTITION BY WATERREADINGS.meter_id,WATERREADINGS.register_id
 ORDER BY WATERREADINGS.meter_id DESC,WATERREADINGS.register_id 
 DESC,WATERREADINGS.readingdate ASC,WATERREADINGS.created ASC
 ) AS prev_water_reading,
 FROM WATERREADINGS
 WHERE waterreadings.waterreadingdate BETWEEN '24-JUN-19' AND 
 '24-AUG-19' and isactive = 'Y'
```

The prev_water_reading value must not be restricted by the date `BETWEEN '24-JUN-19' AND '24-AUG-19'` predicate but the rest of the sql should be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by first finding the previous meter readings for all rows and then filtering those results on the date, e.g.:

```
WITH meter_readings AS (SELECT waterreadings.name,
                               waterreadings.date dt,
                               lag(waterreadings.meter_reading, 1, NULL) OVER (PARTITION BY waterreadings.meter_id, waterreadings.register_id
                                                                               ORDER BY waterreadings.readingdate ASC, waterreadings.created ASC)
                                 AS prev_water_reading,
                        FROM   waterreadings
                        WHERE  isactive = 'Y')
-- the meter_readings subquery above gets all rows and finds their previous meter reading.
-- the main query below then applies the date restriction to the rows from the meter_readings subquery.
SELECT name,
       date,
       prev_water_reading,
FROM   meter_readings
WHERE  dt BETWEEN to_date('24/06/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy') AND to_date('24/08/2019', 'dd/mm/yyyy');
```

Answer (score 0):

I've added a subquery with previous result without filter and then joined it with the main table with filters:

```
SELECT
 WATERREADINGS.name,
 WATERREADINGS.date,
 w_lag.prev_water_reading
FROM 
   WATERREADINGS, 
   (SELECT name, date, LAG( WATERREADINGS.meter_reading,1,NULL) OVER(
    PARTITION BY WATERREADINGS.meter_id,WATERREADINGS.register_id
    ORDER BY WATERREADINGS.meter_id DESC,WATERREADINGS.register_id 
    DESC,WATERREADINGS.readingdate ASC,WATERREADINGS.created ASC
    ) AS prev_water_reading
    FROM WATERREADINGS) w_lag
WHERE waterreadings.waterreadingsdate BETWEEN '24-JUN-19' AND '24-AUG-19' and isactive = 'Y'
 and WATERREADINGS.name = w_lag.name
 and WATERREADINGS.date = w_lag.date
```

Comment: Please add an explanation to your answer - what did you change and why?

Answer (score 0):

Perform the `LAG` in an inner query that is not filtered by dates and then filter by the dates in the outer query:

```sql
SELECT name,
       "date",
       prev_water_reading
FROM   (
  SELECT name,
         "date",    
         LAG( meter_reading,1,NULL) OVER(
           PARTITION BY meter_id, register_id
           ORDER BY meter_id DESC, register_id DESC, readingdate ASC, created ASC
         ) AS prev_water_reading,
       waterreadingdate    -- 
  FROM   WATERREADINGS
  WHERE  isactive = 'Y'
)
WHERE   waterreadingdate BETWEEN DATE '2019-06-24' AND DATE '2019-08-24'
```

You should also not use strings for dates (that require an implicit cast using the `NLS_DATE_FORMAT` session parameter, which can be changed by any user in their own session) and use date literals `DATE '2019-06-24'` or an explicit cast `TO_DATE( '24-JUN-19', 'DD-MON-RR' )`.

You also do not need to reference the table name for every column when there is only a single table as this clutters up your code and makes it difficult to read and `DATE` is a keyword so you either need to wrap it in double quotes to use it as a column name (which makes the column name case sensitive) or should use a different name for your column.

Comment: Hi thank you for quick reply i will try it out. i adjusted my sql i do have other tables in this query.